# Picasso isn't loading scrolled images efficiently?

Tags: android, picasso

I am using a gridview that loads a bunch of images through picasso. I have implemented viewholders and I'm not sure what else I could do with the adapter or imageview to make it load better. I've isolated the issue to the image loading through an internet connection because the scrolling is fine when I load images locally.

The gridview scrolling is very buggy when using picasso and the scroll jumps around constantly when it shouldn't. What is the solution to this issue?

Comment: I think because of high resoltion image, it give this type issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I suggest you to use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` or `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`. It must be more effective and view itself contain less bugs.

Next, use OkHttp with Picasso. It's more stable, powerful and consistent http client. And I think most important to you configure memory/file cache.

```
// Create a cache using an appropriate portion of the available RAM
Cache memoryCache = new LruCache(getApplicationContext());

// Use OkHttp as downloader
Downloader downloader = new OkHttpDownloader(getApplicationContext(),
                    PICASSO_DISK_CACHE_SIZE);

mPicasso = new Picasso.Builder(getApplicationContext())
              .downloader(downloader).memoryCache(memoryCache).build();
```

Speed of loading also depend on network condition and image size.